# Erro data Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine

Estou tentando trazer os valores do banco de dados e apresentar na tela, porém 
ele me da a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
ErrorException in helpers.php line 531:
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /var/www/resources/views/contas/index.blade.php)
```

Eu percebi que esse erro é apresentado quando eu tento apresentar o valor de datas.

**Função:**

```
public function Index(EntityManagerInterface $em)
{
    $FinContaspagar = $em->getRepository(FinContaspagar::class)->findAll();

     return view('contas.index', [ 'FinContaspagar' => $FinContaspagar ]);
}
```

**Index:**

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <h3>Contas cadastradas</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <tr>
                <th>Grupo</th>
                <th>Estabelecimento</th>
                <th>Terceiro</th>
                <th>Codigo</th>
                <th>Data de Emissão</th>
                <th>Data de Vencimento</th>
            </tr>
            @forelse($FinContaspagar as $contas)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $contas->getGrupo() }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $contas->getEstabelecimento() }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $contas->getTerceiro() }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $contas->getCodigo() }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $contas->getDtemissao() }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $contas->getDtvencimento() }}</td>
                </tr>
            @empty
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="5">Não há ações neste momento!</td>
                </tr>
            @endforelse
        </table>

    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Se eu dou um `print_r($FinContaspagar)`, eu obtenho os valores:

```
[0] => ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\FinContaspagar Object
    (
        [grupo:ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\FinContaspagar:private] => 1
        [estabelecimento:ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\FinContaspagar:private] => 1
        [terceiro:ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\FinContaspagar:private] => 1
        [codigo:ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\FinContaspagar:private] => 1
        [dtemissao:ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\FinContaspagar:private] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-04-11 00:00:00
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => UTC
            )

        [dtvencimento:ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\FinContaspagar:private] => DateTime Object
            (
                [date] => 2017-04-11 00:00:00
                [timezone_type] => 3
                [timezone] => UTC
            )

    )
```

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mensagem de erro é bem clara: valores que deveriam ser string são objetos.

Acontece que utilizando o Blade, quando fizer:

```
{{ $var }}
```

O valor de `$var` será passado à função `htmlentities` do PHP e a mesma espera uma string como parâmetro. Qualquer valor que não for string gerará o erro. Verificando seu `print_r` fica claro que tanto o campo `dtemissao` quanto o `dtvencimento` são instâncias da classe `DateTime` e, portanto, não pode ser feito da maneira que fez:

```
<td>{{ $contas->getDtemissao() }}</td>
<td>{{ $contas->getDtvencimento() }}</td>
```

Para transformar estes objetos em string, utilize o método `format`. Acredito que fazer algo como:

```
<td>{{ $contas->getDtemissao()->format("d-m-Y") }}</td>
<td>{{ $contas->getDtvencimento()->format("d-m-Y") }}</td>
```

Resolverá seu problema.

Para mais informações, veja a [documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/datetime.format.php).

Comment: Eu fiz esse teste dentro da função, esqueci de realizar dentro do index. Muito obrigado!